# How to add UNION with pagination in drupal 7 query?

Tags: database

My query is like :

```
$query_club = db_select('club_members','cm');
$query_club->fields('cm',array('first_name','last_name'));
$query_club->group_by('cm.uid');

$query_network = db_select('network_members','nm');
$query_network->fields('nm',array('first_name','last_name'));
$query_network->group_by('nm.uid');

$query_club->union($query_network, 'UNION');
$result = $query_club->execute()->fetchAll();
```

And its giving me correct result.

I want to add here pagination,

```
$query_club = $query_club->extend('PagerDefault')->extend('TableSort');
```

But its not working. Can any one help me out

Comment: You seem to be missing a `->limit($max)`, could it be as simple as that?

Comment: I have used that earlier but forgot mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution. I added this whole query as in subquery like,

```
$query_club = db_select('club_members','cm');
$query_club->fields('cm',array('first_name','last_name'));
$query_club->group_by('cm.uid');

$query_network = db_select('network_members','nm');
$query_network->fields('nm',array('first_name','last_name'));
$query_network->group_by('nm.uid');

$query_club->union($query_network, 'UNION');

**$query_pagination = db_select($query_club,'club_network')->fields('club_network');
$query_pagination = $query_pagination->extend('PagerDefault')->extend('TableSort');
$query_pagination->limit(10)->orderByHeader($header);**

$result = $query_pagination->execute()->fetchAll();
```

And using custom form table `$form['pager'] = array('#markup' => theme('pager'));`
pagination working fine now

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where anything could be wrong, or why it's not working -- I suspect it might have to the do with the `union` but I'm only guessing.

Try these 2 things and see if 1 works for you:

1. Change your first db_select to `$query_club = db_select('club_members','cm')->extend('PagerDefault')->extend('TableSort');`. This may help, i'm not 100% sure.
2. leaving your query as-is and using [pager_default_initialize](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/pager_default_initialize/7) directly in your code. See the examples and comments on the API page.